# Facebook authentication with nodejs

Tags: facebook, node.js, authentication, request, response

I'm trying to authenticate user in facebook:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

getCookies(function(cookies){
  logIn(cookies);
});

function logIn(cookies) {
  var post_data = querystring.stringify({
      'email': 'email@domain',
      'pass': 'password'
  });

  var post_options = {
      host: 'www.facebook.com',
      port: '80',
      path: '/login.php?login_attempt=1',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Content-Length': post_data.length,
          'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
          'set-cookie': cookies[0]
      }
  };

  var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      console.log(res.statusCode);
      var data = '';
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          data += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', function () {
          fs.writeFile("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\fb.html", data, function(err) {
              if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
              } else {
                  console.log("The file was saved!");
              }
          });
      });
  });

  post_req.write(post_data);
  post_req.end();
}

function getCookies(callback){
  var get_options = {
      host: 'www.facebook.com',
      port: '80',
      path: '/',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
      }
  };

  var get_req = http.request(get_options, function(res) {
      var cookies = res.headers['set-cookie'];
      res.on('end', function (chunk) {
          callback(cookies);
      });
  });

  get_req.write('');
  get_req.end();
}
```

But the response is that cookies in my browser are not enabled. Please don't suggest using existing libraries for connecting to facebook, I'm learning... Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses OAuth authentication to authenticate an user. I have used oAuth module to get access to the Linkedin APIs at http://nabaruns.blogspot.in/2013/01/linkedin-api-call-using-nodejs-oauth.html. You can try the same and see if you can call graph facebook apis.

Hope this helps